# Delete rows from a parquet table using Pyspark using storage account trigger

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm trying to figure out a pattern to delete rows from a table in my data lake.  The data lake is an Azure data lake gen2 and I'm using a Synapse Notebook writing code in PySpark.  I have a service bus that get messages when an object has an insert or update that I'm processing in two steps:

1. A service listening to the service bus and plops the message down in my Bronze storage account as a parquet file with a json structure.
2. When that file appears in the Bronze file path it triggers a storage account trigger in Synapse that runs a pipeline that runs a Synapse Notebook to process the insert/update to the Silver layer.  The Silver layer is an auto partitioned parquet file in the Azure data lake.

Sometimes rows get deleted, and I'm sure I could create a message with the ObjectId and a message type of delete.  I can then plop that message in a Bronze file path.  What I'm looking for is how would I then delete the row from the partition parquet file in the Silver layer?

Comment: Could you provide the approach and code that you used for deleting rows?

Comment: How is the data partioned in storage account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to delete rows from `parquet` files and all "solutions" bring many issues with them. This is why formats like
[delta](https://delta.io/), [hudi](https://hudi.apache.org/), [iceberg](https://iceberg.apache.org/) have been created. They support
`DELETE` and ensure ACID properties of your operation. Here is a good start for Synapse + Delta: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-what-is-delta-lake).